# What's the point of giving 2GB of RAM to a YugabyteDB master node if the default limit is to use 10% of those 2GB?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm poking around the mem_tracker code and I have found this comment:
https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/v2.9.1/src/yb/util/mem_tracker.cc#L266

```
// - 10% of the RAM for masters.
```

So the obvious question is: what's the point of giving 2GB of RAM to a master node if the default limit is to use 10% of those 2GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are defaults and can be overwritten by the `default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.1` flag. The idea is that if there's a master and tserver on the same node, we allow 10% to master, 85% to tserver (and remains  5% to system + PostgreSQL work_mem + filesystem buffers).

If you have a node that runs only the master, then clearly this should be changed. But usually, masters are started on the same nodes as tservers.